# Lebesgue integral over $\mathbb R^2$ of the function $f(x,y)=2(x-y)e^{-(x-y)^2}\chi_{\{x>0\}}$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ be given by $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}2(x-y)e^{-(x-y)^2}& \text{ if }x>0 \\0&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$ Given that $\int^\infty_{-\infty} e^{-z^2} dz=\sqrt \pi$ compute $$\int_{\mathbb R^2}|f(x,y)|dxdy$$ Using Tonelli's theorem I was able to reduce this to $$\int_{\mathbb R}\int_{\mathbb R_+^*}|2(x-y)e^{-(x-y)^2}|dxdy$$ But I have no idea how to proceed. I thought about using a change of variables but I couldn't find how to do that with a Lebesgue-intergral...

Comment: Use the reverse order of integration. This should make things easier!

Comment: Although the basic theorems like change-of-variable formula have to be proved again for the Lebesgue integral, they work the same as for Riemann integral. For piecewise continuous functions the two integrals agree, apart from the issues of improper integrals (Lebesgue construction requires absolute convergence).